# How to get domain name instead of an IP in express request?

Tags: javascript, express, http, url, dns

I have an issue when trying to get request domain name on server. But sometimes i will show an IP and sometimes it will show correct domain name. How can i get only the domain when ever i request to server ? Can you guys help me in this ? Thank you guys.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 const host = req.headers.host;
 console.log("Host ",req.headers.host)
})
```

Comment: Well it depends on how your request is being generated. If someone (or someting) is calling it using an ip address, there is no domain. DNS is just a mapping from a string (the domain) to an ip address

Comment: Think of your web page as an office and the internet is the postal service. Your office might have multiple addresses but they all point to the same place. If I get a letter for address x then I can't say, but what's the REAL address for this